# Define common swagger annotation

Tags: java, annotations, swagger

Admittedly, I didn't look too hard for an answer.  My question is, when defining swagger annotations using *springfox-swagger-ui*, how does one define common *ApiResponse* used for more then one method and potentially more then one class?

See the 2 sample methods below the common *ApiResponse* is error 500.  Ideally, I would want to define that once. Any best practices and/or suggestions?

Sample code below:

```
@GET
@Path("/greeting")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@ApiOperation(value = "Returns greeting details", notes = "Returns .....", response = Greeting.class)
@ApiResponses(value = {
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Successful retrieval of greeting details", response = Greeting.class),
    @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Greeting does not exist"),
    @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal server error")}
)
public Response getGreeting(.....) {
    ...
}


@GET
@Path("/something")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@ApiOperation(value = "Returns something details", notes = "Returns .....", response = Something.class
@ApiResponses(value = {
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Successful retrieval of greeting details", response = Something.class),
    @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Something does not exist"),
    @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal server error")}
)
public Response getSomething(.....) {
    ...
}
```

Specifically referring to:

```
@ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal server error")
```

Thank you, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since [`@ApiResponse`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/annotations#apiresponses-apiresponse) is an annotation, you need to add it for every method you want including it on `@ApiResponses` annotation.

Comment: Which isn't correct, since at least they're inherited by the subclasses of a top class where they're used.

Answer (score 0):

you can create custom annotation which use ApiResponses annotation.
And use this custom annotation at method level.
@ApiResponses()
public @interface CustomApiResponse {}

Comment: @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Successfully retrieved list"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "You are not authorized to view the resource"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Accessing the resource you were trying to reach is forbidden"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "The resource you were trying to reach is not found")
})
public @interface CustomApiResponse {

}

Comment: Please edit your answer with your comment and format your answer (Ctrl+K) with more details